# Using Sidekiq with Mailer to send asynchronous emails [RAILS]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, mailer

So I am currently trying to use the Rails gem 'sidekiq' to send a large number of emails asynchronously, so it does not bog down the load time for the next page.

Everything I have works except for this:

```
FeedbackMailer.invite_contact(current_user, current_business, contact).deliver()
```

This is my own mailer and a set of paramters which it must take to create the email for the client.

The error that gets thrown by sidekiq is this:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

The default_url_options[:host] is set in the application.rb, but does not seem to get read here. I also tried setting only_path: true and got the same error still.

I can send emails just find when I am outside one of sidekiq's workers, the problem only exists there. Anyone know of a workaround so that emails can be sent from sidekiq's workers?

Also before you answer, using Mailer.delay doesnt really solve my problem, because there is alot of other code around the mailing that must go off during every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when your mail is not configured properly. Check that you have something like this in the relevant environment file (production.rb or staging.rb)

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address =>              'smtp.something.com',
  :port =>                  587,
  :domain =>               'yourdomain.com',
  :user_name =>            'account-admin@yourdomain.com',
  :password =>             'your secure password',
  :authentication =>       'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: This is all set up in Production.rb and it works fine in every part of the application except for the /app/workers portion.

Comment: Point you production config for redis to localhost try `rails runner -e production 'FeedbackWorker.perform_async(1,2,3)'`  then `RAILS_ENV=production sidekiq` to run the enqueued work. See if this has problems and to give a little more information

Comment: It is also possible that the "production" sidekiq is not running in production mode on the environment where it is deployed and would therefore be using a non-production config.

Comment: Thanks for your time but in the end I switched to DelayedJob and found that I could accomplish my goal in a much simpler way and did not run into this same problem. For anyone else that has this problem I would say use DelayedJob custom jobs instead, more versatile in general in my experience.

Comment: To be clear, while DelayedJob is something that is easy to set up and has only a dependency on a database, it is generally not a long term solution. For many reasons sidekiq is the best choice for new (and existing) apps.